# Small Chatbot challenge

Tags: python, performance, strings, python-3.x

**The Challenge :**

> You have a list conversations, in which each element is a conversation
>   that is represented as an array of words. You need to create a chatbot
>   that will complete a conversation that is currently in progress,
>   `currentConversation`.
>
> To do that, the chatbot must find the conversation from the given list
>   that has the largest number of unique words that match with words from
>   the `currentConversation`. If there are several conversations that match
>   this condition, the chatbot should use the one that appears first in
>   conversations. If no conversation from the list contains any matching
>   words from `currentCoversation`, the chatbot should leave
>   `currentConversation` as it is.
>
> If there is a conversation that can complete `currentConversation`, the
>   chatbot should find the first word in it that appears after all the
>   matching words. The chatbot should then append this word, along with
>   all the words that follow it in that conversation, to
>   `currentConversation`.
>
> Return the final state of `currentConversation`.
>
> Example
>
> For conversations = `[ ["where", "are", "you", "live", "i", "live",
>   "in", "new", "york"], ["are", "you", "going", "somewhere", "tonight",
>   "no", "i", "am", "too", "tired", "today"], ["hello", "what", "is",
>   "your", "name", "my", "name", "is", "john"]] and currentConversation =
>   ["hello", "john", "do", "you", "have", "a", "favorite", "city", "to",
>   "live", "in", "yes", "it", "is"], the output should be
>   chatBot(conversations, currentConversation) = ["hello", "john", "do",
>   "you", "have", "a", "favorite", "city", "to", "live", "in", "yes",
>   "it", "is", "new", "york"]`.
>
> The second conversation has only one matching word, "you". But the
>   other two conversations both have three unique matching words. In the
>   first conversation, the matches are "you", "live", and "in". In the
>   third conversation, the matches are "hello", "john", and "is". Since
>   we have two options that could complete our current conversation, we
>   should choose the one that appears earlier in the list, so we use the
>   first conversation. In that conversation, the last matching word is
>   "in", so we add the last two words, "new" and "york", to
>   `currentConversation` to complete it.
>
> For conversations = `[ ["lets", "have", "some", "fun"], ["i", "never",
>   "get", "it"], ["be", "aware", "of", "this", "house"], ["he", "will",
>   "call", "her"]] and currentConversation = ["can", "you", "please"],
>   the output should be chatBot(conversations, currentConversation) =
>   ["can", "you", "please"]`.
>
> None of the conversations have any words that match words in
>   `currentConversation`, so we add nothing to it.
>
> Input/Output
>
> `[time limit] 4000ms (py3) [input] array.array.string conversations`
>
> An array of conversations, where each conversation is represented as
>   an array of strings. Each string contains only lowercase English
>   letters.
>
> Guaranteed constraints:
>
> - `1 ≤ conversations.length ≤ 104`
> - `1 ≤ conversations[i].length < 100`
> - `1 ≤ conversations[i][j].length ≤ 15`
>
> `[input] array.string currentConversation`
>
> The conversation in progress, which needs to be completed by the
>   chatbot. Each string contains only lowercase English letters.
>
> Guaranteed constraints:
>
> - `1 ≤ currentConversation.length ≤ 100`
> - `1 ≤ currentConversation[i].length ≤ 15`
>
> `[output] array.string`
>
> The completed `currentConversation`.

**MY SOLUTION** ok i compiled it, it works but it is not fast enough

```
def is_unique(word,wlist):
    nb = 0
    for w in wlist:
        if w == word:
            nb = nb+1
    if nb == 1:
        return True
    return False

def find_max(conversations_stats):
    maxs = conversations_stats[0]
    ind_max = 0
    for x in range(1,len(conversations_stats)):
        if conversations_stats[x] > maxs:
            maxs = conversations_stats[x]
            ind_max = x
    return ind_max, maxs

def chatBot(conversations, currentConversation):
    rslt = currentConversation
    lc = len(conversations)
    conversations_stats = [0 for i in range(lc)]
    conversations_li = [0 for i in range(lc)]
    #for x in range(lc):
    for x, wlist in enumerate(conversations, start=0):   # Python indexes start at zero
        #wlist  = conversations[x]
        #wl = len(wlist)
        conversations_li[x]=0
        conversations_stats[x] = 0
        #for y in range(wl):
        for y, a_word in enumerate(wlist, start=0):
            #a_word = wlist[y]
            if a_word in currentConversation:
                if is_unique(a_word,wlist):
                    conversations_stats[x] = conversations_stats[x] + 1
                    conversations_li[x]=y

        #print('word c'+str(conversations_li[x])+' cc'+str(x)+' :'+a_word)



    # ok the one with max unique matching
    ind_max, maxs = find_max(conversations_stats)
    #seaching for the last match 
    #print(maxs)
    if maxs == 0:
        return rslt
    else:
        wlist  = conversations[ind_max]
        cl=len(wlist)
        for k in range(conversations_li[ind_max]+1,cl):
            rslt.append(wlist[k])
        return rslt
    return rslt
```

Comment: I got a feeling that this question belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: Just posted it on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109831/my-python-program-is-not-fast-enough-can-i-make-it-faster And a reviewer there said that I should post it here !!

Comment: Fine, if this is the case we will answer it here ;)

Comment: @MaLiN2223 Why did you think it would be more appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Mast I just think that this question is an algorithmic problem withc rather than here (as per [On topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ) should be posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but I know that the line is thin.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 Well, we got 4.4k questions in [tag:performance], so it should be fine here. Yes, if the question is specifically about the algorithm and not about the rest of the code, it should be more appropriate on Stack Overflow. But it isn't phrased as such, so Stack Overflow rejects it and points to us. It should be just fine here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `wlist` is a flat list of words, the `is_unique()` function could be written as follows:

```
def is_unique(word, wlist):
    return wlist.count(word) == 1
```

I would write the `find_max()` function like so:

```
def find_max(conversations_stats):
    ind_max = conversations_stats.index(conversations_stats[-1])
    maxs = max(conversations_stats)
    return ind_max, maxs
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply :), For now I wrote    `def find_max(array):    smax = array[0]    ind = 0    for i in range(len(array)): 
   if array[i] > smax:    smax = array[i]    ind = i    return smax, ind`  
Your suggestion looks better, I just tried it and it seems to be missing an import ! for the function max(conversations_stats) on my python server

Comment: @Aness, `max()` is a built-in function. You don't have to import it. Please try `help(max)`.

Comment: Ur right, I used a limited swift based online compiler instead of my usual debian Python, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm the one who is confused, but I think you have misunderstood the phrase "unique words from x". It doesn't mean "the set of words in x that appear only once", it means "the set of words in x, with each word presented only once". So, for instance, the unique words in `["where", "are", "you", "live", "i", "live", "in", "new", "york"]` are `["where", "are", "you", "live", "i","in", "new", "york"]`.

My solution:

```
def chatBot(conversations, currentConversation):
    best_conversation = None
    best_match_count = 0
    current_words = set(currentConversation)
    for conversation in conversations:
        conversation_words = set(conversation)
        match_count = sum([word in conversation_words for word in current_words])
        if match_count > best_match_count:
             best_match_count = match_count
             best_conversation = conversation
    if best_conversation is None:
        return(currentConversation)
    last_match = max([i for i in range(len(best_conversation)) if [best_conversation[i] in currentConversation])
    if last_match == len(best_conversation)-1:
        return(current_conversation)     
    return(currentConversation+best_conversation[last_match+1:]
```